# Is there any closed form of the following nested series?

Tags: summation, closed-form

I am wondering if there is any closed form of the following summation?
$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} (q^i \sum \limits_{j=0}^i \dfrac{a^j}{j!})$ where |q|<1.
I know that $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{\infty} q^i = \dfrac{1}{1-q}$
and also $ \sum \limits_{j=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{a^j}{j!} = e^a $ where |q|<1.

To solve this problem, I think I first need to find the closed form of $ \sum \limits_{j=0}^i \dfrac{a^j}{j!}$ in terms of $a$ and $i$. Then I am going to have only one summation in terms of $i$ (the outer summation), and I can focus on finding the closed form of that.

I hope you can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Try $\sum_{i\ge 0}\sum_{j=0}^if(i,j)=\sum_{j\ge 0}\sum_{i=j}^\infty f(i,j)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of summation:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} q^i \sum_{j=0}^i \frac{a^j}{j!} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a^j}{j!} \sum_{i=j}^\infty q^i = -\frac{1}{q-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(aq)^j}{j!} = -\frac{e^{aq}}{q-1},
$$
for $|q|<1$.

Comment: +1 ... as a suggestion, consider stating the basis for the legitimacy of interchanging the order of summations.

Comment: @Dr. MV thank you. You can do that because of Fubini's theorem.

Comment: There's an easier way to show this.

Comment: Wow! that is really great! thanks a lot. However could you please be so kind to explain how you simplified $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a^j}{j!} \sum_{i=j}^\infty q^i$ to $ -\frac{1}{q-1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(aq)^j}{j!}$

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{i=j}^\infty q^i = -\frac{q^j}{q-1}$.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.